# substract a day from a date based on a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to display an output when a certain column which contain dates equals the last day of a month then another column which also contains other dates should equal the same date minus 1 day

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN s.audit_date <> null
         THEN us.processing_date = s.audit_date - 1 END processing_date
  , g.mobile_no
  FROM customers cu
 INNER JOIN gsm.mobile_no g ON g.id = cu.id;
```

but unfortunately this doesn't work..

Comment: i don`t see any alias as 'us' which u have used for the us.processing_date

Comment: "This doesn't work" is not an error message and doesn't explain what problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems that I can see with your query.

1. You are missing a comma after the s.audit_date to provide valid T-SQL syntax
2. In your CASE statement you are attempting to set a column value, just return the value you want.

> ```
>   select us.processing_date, s.audit_date,
>         CASE  
>         WHEN s.audit_date = trunc(s.audit_date, 'MM') THEN s.audit_date - 1
>         END processing_date, g.mobile_no
>  from customers cu
>  inner join gsm.mobile_no g on g.id = cu.id
> ```

Comment: I want to allow the user to select some audit_date and the query should automatically select us.processing_date to be audit_date - 1 day. I don't want to select it manually. Now I have changed my query a bit to reflect any s.audit_Date selection (<> null)

Comment: This is just a small part of the query. I have defined the table and the alias us a bit below when I join the tables

Comment: Agreed. There must be a missing join to a table that was aliased as "s" as well.

Comment: The query is rather long but I defined all tables and their alias properly. The query gives the error on this part. That's why I have posted only that.

Comment: You need to elaborate on your problem here. You cannot set the date on the column in a select query. Do you wish to update the date in the database based upon a user selection?

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, I think you need an `else` clause and to fix the comparison to `NULL`:

```
select (case when s.audit_date is not null then s.audit_date - 1
             else s.processing_date
        end) as processing_date, g.mobile_no
from customers cu inner join
     gsm.mobile_no g
     on g.id = cu.id;
```